# How to run a windows docker container on linux host?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, windows-server-2008, rdp

can we run a windows docker container on linux host? also can take a RDP to windows docker container hosted on linux from other windows machines in the same network?

Answer (score 10):

Today, it is clearly possible.

I recently succeeded in containerizing Windows Guest using QEMU and Docker.

https://github.com/gnh1201/docker-qemu/wiki/Windows-Guest

Answer (score 2):

"windows docker": if that means docker for windows, running [Windows container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/manage_docker), then no.

You could run windows container on Linux the same way you are running Linux Container on windows: through a Virtual Machine emulating the target host.

Update Dec. 2016: Kubernetes 1.5 might offer a solution: see "[Linux machine with docker deploy windows container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33190605/6309)"

Comment: A docker-compose that handles both qemu and preinstalled isos might be possible. If https://stefanscherer.github.io/run-linux-and-windows-containers-on-windows-10/ is true, the opposite can't be impossible.

Comment: @erm3nda I agree. I suppose it will be possible one day.

Answer (score 0):

As VonC answered, it is not possible ATM.

Nevertheless you may consider to run [wine](https://hub.docker.com/r/jess/wine/) if the service you need to run can run with wine.

Answer (score -4):

About RDP, I see this extract from

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/work_in_progress

`Remote Desktop
Windows Containers cannot be managed/interacted with through a RDP session in TP4.`

Comment: hey guys add a comment when you don't like an answer. we need to know why it is not a good answer. please and thank you!