# Is it possible to run applications compiled using IBM XLC/C++ compiler on Docker?

Tags: docker, aix

I have a native application which is compiled on IBM AIX 7.1 Operating System using XL C/C++ compiler. Is it possible to run the application using docker which is installed on Linux machine? I tried to find the base image for IBM AIX OS, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: AFAIK, Docker runs on Windows10/x86 and Linux/x86, not on AIX/Power.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I am not looking for a way to install docker on AIX/Power. I am rather looking for a way to run application compiled on AIX/Power on a docker running on Windows/Linux

Comment: I'm afraid Docker (or a Virtual Machine) cannot run an executable written for another CPU. That would require a PowerPC-emulator (if such thing exist at all). BTW: what is the actual problem you wish to solve (I mean what is X in this XY-problem?)

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond The question was a result of my misunderstanding about docker container and runtime. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102389/how-do-you-run-an-exe-file-on-docker answer cleared my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

No. You could use `qemu` to emulate a powerpc processor but there is no full AIX emulation to run usermode programs. It would also run rather more slowly.