# Docker Windows Containers - Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi3, azure-cosmosdb

I have a cluster of Raspberry Pi 3 (Model B). Can you run *Docker For Windows* containers on Raspberry Pi's running Linux?

I wanted to run the *Azure Cosmos DB Local Emulator* on them for some, and their Docker Image is Windows Containers only and run some .NET Core Apps against the Local Emulator on the Pi.

Comment: No, Docker For **Windows** won't run on **Linux**.
You can install docker on a raspberry pi running linux with:
`curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | bash`

For the Windows Containers running there part tho I'd recommend you reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158596/can-windows-containers-be-hosted-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks greyhame :).