# Need more Docker Engine Resources

Tags: docker, archlinux, docker-image

I was able to install docker, as well pull an image on my OS.

Went throughout most of the [Docker Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Docker).

However now I wouldn't know what to do next. It would seem that the official docker docs mention just the Docker Desktop.

Perhaps I was expecting a docker image to work as a VM image. What I would like to accomplish here is being able to install [Code - OSS](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute) without breaking the packages, and their dependencies, of my OS. Since Node.JS < 17 is required.

To my understanding, I could use the image and basically play with the packages there and if something breaks it's just the image that's broken, not my main OS.

Comment: Am I understanding this right? - You‘re new to Docker , installed it and now you‘re trying to run a certain image?

Comment: [docker is not a hypervisor](https://blog.mikesir87.io/2017/05/docker-is-not-a-hypervisor/).  [Docker image is not a virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972099/why-is-the-ubuntu-docker-image-not-a-vm). `However now I wouldn't know what to do next` → Understand [what is docker](https://geekflare.com/understanding-docker-for-beginner/) at all. If you just want to play with multiple environments inside one OS without exact aims then [KVM](https://geekflare.com/understanding-docker-for-beginner/) may be a good choice (it is a Virtual Machine Hypervisor, not Containers)

Comment: @GabeRAMturn, yes. Is my thinking too outrageous?

Comment: No, not outrageous at all. I just wasn't sure if I understood it right. rzlvmp already gave a great answer though.