# ASPNETCORE containers loading on linux server, but "image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform"

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, linux-containers

Another day, another docker problem.
I am currently working on an aspnetcore app in a container that I want to run on an Ubuntu 18.04. 
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
RUN dotnet restore FOLDER
RUN dotnet build FOLDER
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish
(I didn't put names or some steps as copy)
```

In my deployment CI, it returns **image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform**. I have pulled those 2 images directly on the server and they pulled fine.

I have initially build with *--isolation=hyperv*.

I am quite new to linux containers and servers, therefore I am not sure where the problem is coming from...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you cannot run windows containers in Linux.

Taken from [Can Windows Containers be hosted on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158596/can-windows-containers-be-hosted-on-linux)

*Containers are not for virtualization, and they **are using the resources of the host machine**. As a result, for now windows container cannot run "as-is" on linux machine.
**But** - you can do it by using VM - as it works on windows. You can install windows VM on your linux host, which will allow to run windows containers.*

Comment: Oh. That was a fast answer! Thank you. I'm gonna be very ignorant : my linux is an AWS instance. So I'm not sure I can run a Windows VM on a Linux Server....?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to run a Windows VM on Linux, for instance using VirtualBox https://itsfoss.com/install-windows-10-virtualbox-linux/ If you are not tied to that Linux AWS instance, you could just deploy a Windows AWS instance instead so that you can directly run windows docker containers there.

Comment: Thank you, you were the help I needed!