# Dockerfile to install .NET packages on a Linux Container?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I have 2 containers.
Container 1 has Jenkins on a Linux container.
Container 2 has .NET packages and other tools (MSBuild, Wix, Nuget, .NET framework 4.5, 4.6.2, KSign, etc) on a Windows container.

I searched online and I don't think it's feasible to install the software packages on container 2 on a Linux container...

If I'm running Jenkins on a Linux container, is it possible to create a windows container for my pipeline job? How would that work?

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42185265/6309), Docker on Linux would not support directly Windows containers.

> If I'm running Jenkins on a Linux container, is it possible to create a windows container for my pipeline job?

Only if your Linux is running a Windows VM of some sorts ([Wine in Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/suchja/wine), [VBoxHeadless](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/running-virtual-machines-with-virtualbox-5.1-on-a-headless-ubuntu-16.04-lts-server/)), then you might be able to run a Windows container within that VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect a windows node to jenkins master and schedule windows jobs on this server. You can add labels to nodes and in the job restrict where to invoke particular job.