# Are we able to install Microsoft Visual Studio(not Visual Studio code) in Linux Ubuntu for windows from application?

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio

I'm using Linux Ubuntu and for semester project I need to install Microsoft Visual Studio for development of Windows form application and .net application and I have less hard drive space(using 128 SSD hard-disk) to install Virtual Machine So my question is, is there any way to install Microsoft Visual Studio(not Visual Studio code) in Linux Ubuntu for the development of windows from application?

Comment: no, you can't. More then that, Windows Forms is highly depend on Windows API (such as GDI+, for example), so you can't run them on linux

Comment: You could use a Windows VM running inside your OS of choice.

Comment: No, you can't. Straight up Visual Studio is Windows only. There's also a Mac version (Visual Studio for Mac). VS Code runs on many platforms. If you search for "Download Visual Studio" you'll see your choices

Comment: someone could advise you to use [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) for this, but you should always remember, that `W.I.N.E` is stand for `Wine Is Not an Emulator`

Comment: so what about monodevelop is this have enough development capability?

Comment: You could technically use Mono Develop (or any other cross platform C# IDE like Rider) to develop WinForms application, they just won't run (and maybe even won't compile) on Linux

Comment: I recommend you do what my school is forcing us to do: use an external SSD, USB 3.0 or 3.1 (or whatever it's called nowadays) is plenty fast enough, you can save your VMs to it and boot them on your laptop. Just make sure your using git or some other form of saving your code, because there's a non-negligible chance of your VM corrupting (due to a few reasons)

Comment: @vasily.sib
Is there any way to setup Visual-studio in Docker container??

Comment: @mobinalhassan you [can't host windows containers on linux host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42185265/2716623)

Comment: @mobinalhassan it doesn't matter if you can install VS (or any other IDE for C#) - you will never able to run WinForms on linux. Never and ever. By no means.

Comment: @vasily.sib WinForms even doesn't work when we run in-side IDE? like we are just run or compile inside IDE?

Comment: @mobinalhassan yes, I repeat - you will never able to run WinForms on linux. Never and ever. By no means. Even on _"just run or compile inside IDE"_

Comment: MonoDevelop has its own GTK based WinForms-style framework you can use, IIRC.

Comment: @vasily.sib Thanks .

Answer (score -3):

It is not possible to install Microsoft Visual Studio on Linux Ubuntu. See this link of the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/compatibility)

You will not be able to develop a Windows Forms application on a Linux machine, Microsoft indicated that WPF and WinForms will be Windows only with no plans to move them cross-platform, even if you use .NET Core.

Comment: There is nothing like to install or use in linux

Comment: This is just not true

Comment: Where on that page does it say you can install Visual Studio on Linux? Hint: It doesn't.

Comment: Nope. No way. I can't see any description how i can instal VS on Linux.