# Host windows-based docker image on Heroku

Tags: windows, image, docker, heroku

How can I host a windows-based docker image on Heroku?

Here's contents of my docker file

```
FROM stefanscherer/node-windows:10
```

and Heroku deployment fails with this error:

10: Pulling from stefanscherer/node-windows
remote: no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries

Is it possible to do such thing on Heroku?

Comment: It's a general Docker issue. See accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158596/can-windows-containers-be-hosted-on-linux

On Heroku you are running Docker under a Linux system.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.
Windows docker container could not be hosted on Linux.