# Running windows .exe in Linux environment (other alternatives to "Wine" and VM)

Tags: python, linux, singularity-container

I have this problem I was trying to solve for quite some time now:
I have **windows executable** that I call from a Python script using (subprocess.run()) as a way of automating my simulations. These simulations take days to complete, so in order to keep using my computer in the proper conditions, I decided to run them in a cluster I have access to. These executable could be called there (a Linux environment) using "Wine". This solution cannot be implemented because I am not root. I found an alternative: "Singularity". My very small knowledge in this domain did not allow me to fully comprehend how I can make a good use of it. In other words, what are the changes I need to make in my initial Python file, where the two lines that cause problem are: subprocess.run('scad3.exe' '-b' 'myntelist.net') and sb.run([ltsputil.exe, '-xo0', rawfile, txtfig, "%1e", ' ', ' ', '0', 'V(3)']) ?

Ps: Virtual machines cannot be used as well, for security problems..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, and unlikely to be any time in the near future.

See also the related question about running windows containers in docker on a linux host OS: [Can Windows Containers be hosted on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158596/can-windows-containers-be-hosted-on-linux)

Comment: Will do. Thank you for your response :D