# How to install Windows-only NPM package on Ubuntu for development?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-windows

**Context:**

I am developing a node app for Windows 2016 server. The machine I develop on runs Ubuntu 18.04.

I would like to make use of the package `node-windows`, however when I try to install it, I get the following error:

```sh
$ npm i node-windows
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for node-windows@1.0.0-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

**Question:**

While it makes sense to me that I will not be able to run the app on Linux, I am looking for a way that allows me to write and hopefully build the code on Linux.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Dockerize your app, or install virtual machine

Comment: I like the idea of having the app run in a docker container, however per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158596/can-windows-containers-be-hosted-on-linux , it is not possible to run windows docker images on linux. I would like to avoid writing code within a VM if possible.