# Is it possible to expose gpu in a windows container running on a linux host?

Tags: docker

I am trying to setup a windows container on a linux host (18.04), is it possible to expose the gpu in a way that windows understands it? similar to --device /dev/dri:/dev/dri ?

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't be possible to run Windows in Linux host. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158596/can-windows-containers-be-hosted-on-linux