# Can I run window and linux containers at the same time? Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, zend-framework2

I have a zendframework 2 website that need a linux OS, and the website use a search engine that run on windows OS (IIS). How to use docker to run the website and the search engine at the same time?

Iam new to docker, I will appreciate if someone can help with docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker uses the kernel in the system that you are using on the host machine to run the container, so if you have a linux machine with docker installed you can only run images of containers that uses a linux kernerl.

So you can't have a windows container on a linux machine.
Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42185265) can help