# Is it possible to docker an IIS on a linux docker-mothership

Tags: c#, linux, docker, iis, docker-compose

I have the following challenge.

After switching from PHP to C#, a project has been created that currently requires an IIS.
This is started from Visual Studio and runs on a localhost.

I would like to do this with dockr and if I googled it right, it is possible with a windows container.
However, I only have a Linux system with docker and there is no way there will be anything else.
Docker-Desktop is available, but I don't want to use it, because other employees should be able to access the system.

So is it possible to get an IIS running in a docker-linux, and if so how would that look like.

Of course I would prefer to be able to work with docker-compose.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is a docker-mothership?

Comment: A Linux-System where docker is installed, and the containers should run.

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158596/can-windows-containers-be-hosted-on-linux#:~:text=No%2C%20you%20cannot%20run%20windows,can%20run%20Linux%20on%20Windows.&text=You%20can%20change%20between%20OS,the%20docker%20in%20tray%20menu.&text=Containers%20use%20the%20OS%20kernel.

Comment: Can you use Kestrel instead of IIS?

Comment: There is no linux version of IIS and you can't run windows container on linux, but there is no strong dependecy on IIS, so you can use any other proxy you want

Comment: Kestrel seems to be very promising ... i will have a deeper look in that.

Comment: you can't run a windows-docker-container on linux. you can't run IIS on linux. ergo: no.

Comment: "a project has been created that currently requires an IIS", what kind of project? Like the other comment indicates, if your project is ASP.NET Core based, Kestrel is there already and can go cross platform without IIS.