# How to run .net Framework 4.7.2 in Docker Linux Container?

Tags: linux, docker, .net-4.8

I have a .net framework 4.7.2 application. I have to install the application in Linux. As such I need to deploy it into docker Linux container.

Is there anyway to deploy it into Linux container from Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: why don't you use .NET based image to create a Dockerfile?
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet

Comment: .NET Framework (as opposed to .NET Core which now named .NET) can only run on Windows. Windows container can't run directly on Linux https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158596/can-windows-containers-be-hosted-on-linux without a VM

Comment: Short answer: no. Framework is Windows only. You might be able to run Wine on a container to emulate Windows on Linux and get it to run, but I'm pretty sure that's not a good way to go. The right way is to migrate the app to .NET 5, away from Framework.