# What kernel is Docker using?

Tags: docker

There are base OS images for example, for [Windows](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-base-os-images) and alpine linux. For these OS images, how are they making calls to the kernel? Is Docker providing some abstraction of a kernel?

> Containers share the machine’s OS system kernel

https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container/

Comment: Containers are just processes running on the host OS kernel. There's really not all that much difference between running `ls` at your local shell and running `ls` inside a container; the latter just has a constrained view of available resources.

Comment: (Although note that if you're running Docker under MacOS or Windows, generally "the host kernel" is a Linux viirtual machine, not your actual host OS)

Comment: Where is the documentation on that? Does Docker explain this somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure which comment you're referring to when you ask, "where is the documentation on that?" Re: "a container is just a process", I'm not sure that the docs on docker.com are explicit about that, but a search for "what is a container" will get you lots of good material. Re: "the host kernel is a Linux virtual machine", Docker is built on Linux namespace technology and hence only runs under Linux (except when you are using Docker on Windows to run Windows containers). They reference this e.g. in https://www.docker.com/blog/the-magic-behind-the-scenes-of-docker-desktop/

Comment: @larsks I think his question is that i have an image that is for a containerized 32-bit Windows application built for x86, and i want to run the image on a 64-bit ARM Linux machine. The 32-bit x86 application code, and the Windows 32-bit x86 binaries can't run natively on ARM. So Docker must be providing a translation somewhere - where it converts x86 instructions to ARM instructions. Also x86 code eventually tries to access the hardware using the Windows APIs (e.g. to draw to the screen, or output sound). How is docker intercepting calls to hardware when it's not x86 hardware out there?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can only run Windows containers on Windows (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42185265/147356). If that's changed recently, it's not something with which I have experience.

Comment: @larsks no really, it is possible for some time already https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers

Comment: @IłyaBursov that's the opposite -- that's about running Linux containers on Windows, which has always been possible. I'm saying it's not possible to run Windows container on Linux.