# unable to run windows image on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, iis

I am trying to run my docker windows IIS image which is running perfectly with docker but I want to use kubernetes for the orchestration part. Is there anything that I can do to attain it straight away?

I tried the to do so with the help kubernetes documentation(https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/windows/user-guide/) & below template : -

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: win-webserver
  labels:
    app: win-webserver
spec:
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: win-webserver
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: win-webserver
  name: win-webserver
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: win-webserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: win-webserver
      name: win-webserver
    spec:
     containers:
      - name: windowswebserver
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
        command:
        - powershell.exe
        - -command
        - "<#code used from https://gist.github.com/19WAS85/5424431#> ; $$listener = New-Object System.Net.HttpListener ; $$listener.Prefixes.Add('http://*:80/') ; $$listener.Start() ; $$callerCounts = @{} ; Write-Host('Listening at http://*:80/') ; while ($$listener.IsListening) { ;$$context = $$listener.GetContext() ;$$requestUrl = $$context.Request.Url ;$$clientIP = $$context.Request.RemoteEndPoint.Address ;$$response = $$context.Response ;Write-Host '' ;Write-Host('> {0}' -f $$requestUrl) ;  ;$$count = 1 ;$$k=$$callerCounts.Get_Item($$clientIP) ;if ($$k -ne $$null) { $$count += $$k } ;$$callerCounts.Set_Item($$clientIP, $$count) ;$$ip=(Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetIpAddress); $$header='<html><body><H1>Windows Container Web Server</H1>' ;$$callerCountsString='' ;$$callerCounts.Keys | % { $$callerCountsString+='<p>IP {0} callerCount {1} ' -f $$ip[1].IPAddress,$$callerCounts.Item($$_) } ;$$footer='</body></html>' ;$$content='{0}{1}{2}' -f $$header,$$callerCountsString,$$footer ;Write-Output $$content ;$$buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($$content) ;$$response.ContentLength64 = $$buffer.Length ;$$response.OutputStream.Write($$buffer, 0, $$buffer.Length) ;$$response.Close() ;$$responseStatus = $$response.StatusCode ;Write-Host('< {0}' -f $$responseStatus)  } ; "
     nodeSelector:
      kubernetes.io/os: windows
```

but error: above template has error 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling

Comment: The error message approximately says there isn't a Windows node in your cluster.  As an application developer there's nothing you can do about that; you'll have to work with your operations team to get that set up.

Comment: What are the ways that I can use to create a windows node in my cluster. Can you suggest me any references or blogs?

Answer (score 1):

Containers are using the underlying operating system resources and drivers, so Windows containers can run on Windows node only, and Linux containers can run on Linux node only.

For more details:
[Can Windows containers be hosted on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158596/can-windows-containers-be-hosted-on-linux)

Comment: ok. So, how can i configure windows node?

Comment: Are you using any cloud provider like aws, azure, GCP for your kubernetes setup?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/windows/intro/

Comment: No, I am trying this deployment with local env. @Sat21343

Comment: Are you using minikube for this setup?