# How does Docker know nothing about my operating system?

Tags: docker

The first page of the Docker documentation, ["What is a container?"](https://docs.docker.com/guides/walkthroughs/what-is-a-container/), claims,

> A container is an isolated environment for your code. This means that
> a container has no knowledge of your operating system, or your
> files.

Let's assume I'm running Docker on a computer running GNU/Linux.   My understanding is that Docker uses cgroups, namespaces, and an overlay file system to provide isolation.  All of these are provided by the Linux kernel.  Docker will not work without these features.  Hence why Docker only works with versions of Linux that have them.  As far as I understand, [Docker was unavailable for other systems, such as Windows, until similar features were added to those operating systems](https://web.archive.org/web/20230328004205/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/april/containers-bringing-docker-to-windows-developers-with-windows-server-containers) or [until Docker was updated with a VM work with them](https://www.docker.com/blog/the-magic-behind-the-scenes-of-docker-desktop/).

What Am I missing?  How can a container require certain operating system features yet have no knowledge of the operating system?

Comment: The container _"runs on the environment provided to you by Docker Desktop"_. _Docker Desktop_ has to know things about your OS, but provides an abstraction so that _the container_ (and your code in it) doesn't.

Comment: Docker the engine knows the host OS and its features. The containers it runs don't need that knowledge or access.

Comment: It's called abstraction.

Comment: If you also define "operating system" as including non-kernel things like system libraries and daemons, these are in fact inaccessible inside a container.  Also note that the container runtime can take advantage of host-OS features while hiding them from the containers it launches.

Comment: Interesting.  It seems that containers are able to access the kernel directly, though: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/docker-container-kernel-modules

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow is geared towards programming and development questions, and this is not one of them. Possibly the more appropriate place for this question is Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question that lies at the  intersection of several ambiguous terms.  That's probably why it's so contentious.  Because my question was genuine, not specific to Unix or Linux, "about something happening inside the container" (and so "probably on-topic here"), undoubtedly held by others, and still visible from search engines, I'd like to answer my own question with what I've learned elsewhere.

**The Docker documentation is either simply incorrect or, at best, misleadingly inaccurate.**

The *defining characteristic* of a container is that it *directly* uses the host system's kernel<sup>1</sup>.

Docker containers require 3 features of the host operating system:

1. process partitioning
2. resource limiting
3. a union file system

Linux does this with 1) namespaces, 2) cgroups, and 3) AuFS.  Windows provides analogous features.

Speaking positively, what does it mean to *have knowledge* of your operating system?

It seems reasonable to say that being able to make direct system calls to the host operating system constitutes some form of "knowledge of your operating system."

For example, [as far as I'm aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42185265), it's not possible to use namespaces, cgroups, and the union file system on Linux to run a Windows container.  You can't run a Windows container *directly* on Linux at all!  In simple terms, you call `fork()` to create a new process on Linux and Windows uses `CreateProcess()`.  A container on a Linux host only knows `fork()`.   That is, it knows about the host operating system.

A similar argument applies for limiting resources.

If you define an operating system as the files on the file system, then, yes, the container has no knowledge of your "operating system."  It's helpful to note that a container "[image](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/spec.md#image-format-specification)" is more-or-less a tarball of file system layers along with information to correctly set up the container.  On a GNU/Linux host, when you run Rocky in one container and Debian in another, they're still using the same Linux kernel.  That's why you can't (or shouldn't allow containers to) modify the kernel.  The same kernel is used for all containers (including the host operating system (which also runs in a container)). The Docker documentation correctly states that containers have no knowledge of your (host system's) files.

Some argue that the container knows *nothing* about the host operating system.  Instead, it's Docker *Engine* or Docker *Desktop* or *containerd* or *runc* or whatever.  At that point, we're basically arguing over "What is knowledge?", "What is an operating system?", "What is a container?", and "What is Docker?"  These are interesting and important questions, especially for good documentation and an industry to figure out.  However, they're not questions for Stackoverflow.

<sup>1</sup> Otherwise, as far as I understand, it's a virtual machine or some other user space process.