# Running windows container on linux host

Tags: linux, windows, docker, cross-platform

I installed docker CE on an Ubuntu 16.04, and when I try:

```
docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore
```

It fails:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from microsoft/windowsservercore
3889bb8d808b: Pulling fs layer 
da87b55a9b63: Pulling fs layer 
image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform
```

Is it possible to run a windows image on a linux host with docker? If yes, how should I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux machine with docker deploy windows container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190469/linux-machine-with-docker-deploy-windows-container)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike other Virtual computing systems like Virtual Box or VMWare, Docker images are small and not fully complete stand alone entities.

The Docker image does not include the OS kernel, instead it uses the kernel of the Docker host

This makes the images very light weight, but it also means you won't be able to run a Windows image on a Linux host.