# Is there any way to run an image Windows Docker on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, ubuntu, containers

I would like to know if there is any way to start a container from a Windows Docker image.

The idea would be to start a Windows container on my Ubuntu and then connect   by RDP to that Windows machine. It is possible?

Comment: I'd expect that you'd need to run the Docker image in a Windows environment e.g. running in VirtualBox running Windows running Docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Docker success center](https://success.docker.com/article/does-docker-for-windows-server-2016-support-gui-based-applications):

> At this time, no, Docker for Windows Server 2016 does not support GUI-based applications. This is because Windows containers are based on either Nano or Core Server, which do not allow users to start up a GUI-based interface nor RDP into the container.

And concerning running Windows containers on Ubuntu, you can find other posts related to that : [Can window containers be hosted on linux ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158596/can-windows-containers-be-hosted-on-linux) and [Linux machine with docker deploy windows container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190469/linux-machine-with-docker-deploy-windows-container/33190605#33190605)