# How to copy an exe file to App Engine (flex) with Go runtime?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, dockerfile, app-engine-flexible

My Go application needs to use a stand-alone executable, which I would like to copy it along with 'gcloud app deploy' command during deployment to GAE flex environment.

1. I have tried keeping the exe in the folder where other go files are located during deploy, but this doesn't seem to take the exe to the GAE flex
2. I tried using these 2 lines in Dockerfile and changed the "runtime: custom" in app.yaml, but that didn't fix either, as I am missing few more things it seems.

> ```
> FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/golang 
> ADD test.exe /usr/local/bin/
> ```

Can anyone suggest, without/with Dockerfile, how can I copy the test.exe and also build the go application on a GAE flex environment?

**EDIT:**
**I realize I should install the package (Debian package) on the GAE machine itself, and make it available for the App Engine app.**

Any pointers on how to prepare the Dockerfile so that the Debian package is installed with all its dependencies and is also accessible to the app that I am deploying to App Engine?

Comment: I edited my answer with some options. Why do you need Debian?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a file using the command `COPY`.

However, it will not work, since the VM running the GAE flex instance uses Linux as seen in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685973/is-there-any-way-to-run-an-image-windows-docker-on-ubuntu).

I also found this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898224/is-it-possible-to-run-a-windows-executable-in-google-app-engine-flexible-env), it may be helpful for you.

**EDIT**

Other options you have to deploy your application, which is in need of a windows executable file, is to create a VM instance with Windows and deploy your application there. Or you could find an alternative for that stand-alone executable for Linux, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Pablo. Based on your input did some research, and updated my query realizing I won't be able to copy the exe directly, instead the debian package needs to be installed in the environment during build.