# Why does this Docker FAQ say that containers don't contain OS inside it?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel

This FAQ from the official Docker [page](https://www.docker.com/blog/the-10-most-common-questions-it-admins-ask-about-docker/) (cached [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:O-U9SUxpEvYJ:https://www.docker.com/blog/the-10-most-common-questions-it-admins-ask-about-docker/%20&cd=20&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in)) says:

> Unlike VMs, containers do not have an OS within it. They simply share
> the underlying kernel with the other containers.

OS is usually defined as `kernel + shell`. So, why is the above FAQ stating that OS is not there inside the container, when almost all images have a barebones OS present in them (except for the rarely used case when images are created from scratch)?

Images don't have the OS kernel inside them, but they *do* have an OS in all practical cases.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is the power of docker!

Containers, expecially under linux, are based on the concept of [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces). **Namespaces** allow to implement the concept of [process isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation).

So, each container relies on the hosting OS by its own kernel, and offers services by different OS distribution packaged inside **docker images**.

The exception is, for example, a Windows container on Linux which requires a VM. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190469/linux-machine-with-docker-deploy-windows-container/33190605#33190605) for further information.